# How to create a variable that persists over tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate evaluation steps?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

**TLDR: How to create a variable that holds the confusion matrix used for computing custom metrics, accumulating the values across all of the evaluation steps?**

I [have implemented](https://github.com/sdll/psenet/blob/6bf02235a5f8bc7b09845c12ae0d0c9078ac0159/psenet/utils/metrics.py#L198) custom metrics to use in the `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluation` pipeline, with a confusion matrix as the crux for them all. My goal is to make this confusion matrix persist over multiple evaluation steps in order to track the learning progress.

Using `get_variable` in the variable scope did not work, since it does not save the variable to the checkpoint (or so it seems).

This does not work:

```py
    @property
    def confusion_matrix(self):
        with tf.variable_scope(
            f"{self.name}-{self.metric_type}", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE
        ):
            confusion_matrix = tf.get_variable(
                name="confusion-matrix",
                initializer=tf.zeros(
                    [self.n_classes, self.n_classes],
                    dtype=tf.float32,
                    name=f"{self.name}/{self.metric_type}-confusion-matrix",
                ),
                aggregation=tf.VariableAggregation.SUM,
            )
        return confusion_matrix
```

Just saving the matrix as a class attribute works, but it obviously does not persist over multple steps:

```py
        self.confusion_matrix = tf.zeros(
            [self.n_classes, self.n_classes],
            dtype=tf.float32,
            name=f"{self.name}/{self.metric_type}-confusion-matrix",
        )
```

You can look at the full example [here](https://github.com/sdll/psenet/blob/6bf02235a5f8bc7b09845c12ae0d0c9078ac0159/psenet/utils/metrics.py#L52).

I expect to have this confusion matrix persist from end to finish during evaluation, but I do not need to have it in the final SavedModel. Could you please tell me how I can achieve this? Do I need to just save the matrix to an external file, or there is a better way?

Comment: have you tried `tf.metrics.mean_tensor` during evaluation inside `model_fn`?

Comment: @alexey, I [convert](https://github.com/sdll/psenet/blob/6bf02235a5f8bc7b09845c12ae0d0c9078ac0159/psenet/train.py#L195) a `tf.keras` model to the estimator, and then add the metrics with `tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics`. The custom metrics [do use](https://github.com/sdll/psenet/blob/6bf02235a5f8bc7b09845c12ae0d0c9078ac0159/psenet/utils/metrics.py#L218) `tf.metrics.mean` under the hood, but I am not sure whether this guarantees that they persist over evaluation steps. Could you please expand on your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom metric:

```
def confusion_matrix(labels, predictions):
    matrix = ... # confusion matrix calculation
    mean, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_tensor(matrix)
    # do something with mean if needed
    return {'confusion_matrix': (mean, udpate_op)}
```

and then add it to your `estimator`:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, confusion_matrix)
```

if you need sum instead of meen you can take insight from `tf.metrics.mean_tensor` implementation

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see how this answers my question, sorry if the wording is confusing. All of the metrics I have implemented use the same confusion matrix under the hood. However, at the moment I create an object with a confusion matrix for each of them instead. It would be nice to create the variable once and use it for each evaluation step, updating it once after inference and then basing the computation of the custom metrics on its value. As you can see in the code [here](https://git.io/fjQp1) and [here](https://git.io/fjQpM), adding the metrics is not the issue.

Comment: `update_op` is actually executed in every evaluation step and modifies `mean` tensor so it seems like what you need. If you need to calculate different metrics you can do in inside `confusion_matrix` and include in the returned dictionary

Comment: Not sure that I can include them in the returned dictionary, however, because the values of the dictionary must include the update ops. Are you saying that I need  to operate on `mean` from `mean, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_tensor(matrix)`, and then wrap the results in `mean_tensor` as well?

Comment: Yeah, `mean` from `mean, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_tensor(matrix)`. 
I think you can reuse `update_op` from `mean_tensor`. This ops modify `sum` and `count` tensors that are required for mean computation.

Comment: @sdll, Can you please confirm if your issue is resolved? If so, can you please specify the Answer here for the benefit of the community. Thanks!