# Is there a way to create a variable that persists over tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate evaluation steps?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have found this :
[How to create a variable that persists over tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate evaluation steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401924/how-to-create-a-variable-that-persists-over-tf-estimator-train-and-evaluate-eval)

But nobody seems to have answered the original question.
For other reasons I need to do this, i.e. have variables that persist each of the steps of the estimator evaluate.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Thanks,